# Why does my code print twice the amount of spaces I expect?

Tags: python

Python provides a built-in function called `len` that returns the length of a string, so the value of `len('allen')` is 5. Write a function named `right_justify` that takes a string named `s` as a parameter and prints the string with enough leading spaces so that the last letter of the string is in column 70 of the display.

Author's solution:

```
def right_justify(s):
        print (' '*(70-len(s))+s)
>>> right_justify('allen')
```

My solution:

```
def right_justify(s):
            space_count=70-len(s)
            for i in range(0,space_count,1):
                       print " ",
            print s
strng=raw_input("Enter your desired string:")
print len(strng)
right_justify(strng)
```

The output of my code is different than the output of author's code: I am getting twice as many spaces, e.g. 130 instead of 65.

But it seems to me that the two pieces of code are logically equivalent. What am I overlooking?

Comment: *Is there any differnce between these codes?* You mean apart from them being literally different?

Comment: What is the output you expect and what is the output your code gives?

Answer (score 2):

The problem is with your print statement

```
print " ",
```

will print *two* spaces for each iteration of the loop. When terminating the print statement with a comma, subsequent calls will be delimited by a space.

On a side note, another way to define your `right_justify` function would be

```
def right_justify(s):
    print '%70s' % s
```

Answer (score 0):

The `print " ",` line actually prints two spaces (one from the `" "`, one from the `,`). You could replace it with `print "",` to have your function work identically to the original.

Answer (score 0):

Your code has 130 spaces, the author's code has 65 spaces. This is because

```
print " ",
```

...adds a space. What you want is:

```
print "",
```

Answer (score 0):

I would prefer the function str.rjust(70," ") which does the trick, I think, like so:
 strng.rjust(70," ")